# Django1.6 UpdateView, how to display field without update it

Tags: django, django-models, django-generic-views

models.py

```py
class Application(models.Model):
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

views.py

```py
class ApplicationUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Application
    template_name = "apps/update.html"
    fields = ['name', 'desc']
    context_object_name = "app"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app-list')
```

templates

```html
    <div class='update-item'>
        {{form.name.error}}
        {{form.name.label_tag}}
        {{form.name}}
    </div>
    <div class='update-item'>
        {{form.desc.value}}
    </div>
```

Here I want to display desc field in template, but only POST name field when update it. Any solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these:

1. Set readonly attributes on fields that you don't want to be changed.
2. Instead of `{{form.desc.value}}` you can display instance field value - `{{ form.instance.desc }}`, next remove `desc` field from `include` attribute.

Comment: yup, it works. But possible don't put desc field in input element?

Comment: @linbo I'm not sure what you're asking.. if you want to display it as text input, just create custom input tag and put `{{ form.instance.desc }}` as value. Just don't set any name attribute for the input, so it won't be picked up by request.

Comment: want to put it in other element, for example in div element, not for input element

Comment: @linbo remove `desc` field from `include` attribute